# How to use an apply on multiple columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Take Pandas df:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 6 |

I want to update df to use the lambda function (lambda x: 1 if x>1 else x) on col1 and col2. How would I do this instead of using apply on each column at a time?

I tried:

```
column_list = ['Col1', 'Col2']

pivot_df[column_list] = pivot_df[column_list].apply(lambda x: 1 if x>1 else x)
```

But got:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Is this a dummy example? Because you would never use `apply` for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html). It will apply the lambda function to each cell.

```
pivot_df[column_list] = pivot_df[column_list].applymap(lambda x: 1 if x>1 else x)
```

Comment: But this is a very bad use case for `applymap`, you should always vectorize when possible

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `apply` for that. If this is the real function you want to run, use [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) instead:

```
df.update(df[['Col1', 'Col2']].clip(upper=1))
```

Or with a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2']

df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].gt(1), 1)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Col1  Col2
0   1     0     0
1   2     1     1
2   3     1     1
```